# WCF OperationContract

Tags: wcf, operationcontract

What is a WCF OperationContract? I dont really understand what it does

Answer (score 44, accepted):

WCF uses an opt-in model to define what belongs to one of its contracts. In a service contract interface, only methods decorated with `[OperationContract]` are exposed to the client. That means that, in the interface below, if used within a WCF service, a client could call both Add and Subtract operations, but not Multiply.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int x, int y);

    [OperationContract]
    int Subtract(int x, int y);

    // Not decorated
    int Multiply(int x, int y);
}
```

Comment: Well, Like I need all methods to be accessed by client, and I don't want to write that on every method, what do I do there?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721554/how-to-apply-operationcontract-to-all-methods-in-interface

Answer (score 7):

Every method you want to be able to the user calling from his client side must be declared like that.