# how to apply OperationContract to all methods in interface

Tags: c#, wcf, attributes, servicecontract, operationcontract

Im creating a service contract in my wcf application and it contains a lot of methods.

I find it very annoying to write an `OperationContract` attribute to all of them.

Is there any simple way how to say "every method in my `ServiceContract` interface is an `OperationContract`" ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use AOP framework for that. E.g. with PostSharp:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class AutoServiceContractAttribute : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    // This method is called at build time and should just provide other aspects.
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        Type targetType = (Type)targetElement;

        var introduceServiceContractAspect =
            new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect( 
                new ObjectConstruction(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute)
                                          .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)));
        var introduceOperationContractAspect =
            new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect( 
                new ObjectConstruction(typeof(OperationContractAttribute)
                                         .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)));

        // Add the ServiceContract attribute to the type.
        yield return new AspectInstance(targetType, introduceServiceContractAspect);

        // Add a OperationContract attribute to every relevant method.
        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        foreach (MethodInfo method in targetType.GetMethods(flags))
        {
            if (!method.IsDefined(typeof(NotOperationContractAttribute), false))
                yield return new AspectInstance(method, introduceOperationContractAspect);
        }
    }
}
```

This attribute used to mark methods which should not be operation contracts:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class NotOperationContractAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Now all you need to do is apply `AutoServiceContract` attribute to service interface. That will add `ServiceContract` attribute to interface, and all public methods will be marked with `OperationContact` attribute (except those which have `NotOperationContract` attribute):

```
[AutoServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    public void Method1();
    [NotOperationContact]
    public string Method2);
    public int Method3(int a);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: is there any free tool for AOP, like PostShartp ?

Comment: @JohnSmith PostSharp has free license (not sure if adding attributes available in free edition). You can take a look on [this AOP frameworks list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to do it on each and every method. it defines an operation that is part of a service contract in a Service. There is a possibility that some of the methods are not intended for Exposing.

Comment: OK, I just hoped there is a way how to say explicitly each method is a part of my service contract. I think Microsoft should support such an option. Nevertheless - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Spring.Net has built-in feature `ServiceExporter` and all you need is such config:

```
<object id="MyServiceExporter" type="Spring.ServiceModel.ServiceExporter, Spring.Services">
  <property name="TargetName" value="MyService" />
  <property name="TypeAttributes">
  <list>
    <object type="System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute, System.ServiceModel">
      <property name="ConfigurationName" value="MyService"/>
    </object>
  </list>
  </property>
</object>
<object id="MyService" singleton="false" type="Eluzzion.TOrder.Service.OrderExportService, Eluzzion.TOrder.Service" />
<object id="MyServiceHost" type="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryObject, Spring.Services" lazy-init="false" >
  <property name="TargetName" value="MyServiceExporter" />
</object>
```

For more details check [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html#d4e8528) and this [forum thread](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?5294-Hosting-a-WCF-service-created-by-the-ServiceExporter). You need to have service definition in `app.config` called same as the Spring object: `MyService`

Next step will be to decorate all objects with `DataContract` attribute. Any ideas? Not very good one is to use `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute on service contracts (can be added by Spring too).